# From geodesic motion of photons to Maxwell equations in curved spacetime

Tags: photons, maxwell-equations, geodesics

In curved spacetime, 1.) a photon is supposed to move along a null-geodesic, i.e., a trajectory $x^{\mu} = x^{\mu}(\lambda)$ satisfying $$\frac{d^{2}x^{\rho}}{d\lambda^2} + \Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda} = 0$$ and $$g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda} = 0$$ in conjunction, for some parameter $\lambda$, while 2.) the source free Maxwell equations are given by $$\nabla_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu} + \Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\rho\mu}F^{\rho\nu} = 0.$$ The former generally depends on all 40 components of the Christoffel connection, while the latter depends only on 4 degrees of freedom of the Christoffel connection (its trace). My question is therefore the following:

Considering, loosely speaking, an electromagnetic wave to be a collection of photons, how can the latter be derived, in some limit(?), from the former? How do most of the degrees of freedom of the Christoffel connection get 'washed out' in any such process? By some averaging or what?

Does the Ricci tensor in the de Rham wave operator figuring in the equations of motion of the electromagnetic four-potential itself perhaps play a role, even though it is of second differential order in the metric whereas the Christoffel symbols are only of first order? I have no idea.

I would appreciate any hint or some reference to relevant literature.

Comment: The proper way to define the motion of an EM wave (the wavefront of an EM wave is on a null hypersurface, to give you the appropriate theorem) is done via the theory of characteristic surfaces of differential equations. For a simpler theory where we consider the motion of curves, you have to deal with the Luneberg-Kline expansion of the EM field, where the low frequency part of the EM field can be described by a scalar field which leads to a divergence vector field whose field lines are null curves.

Comment: Thanks. I have never heard about the Luneburg-Kline expansion. But before perhaps digging into it, does it, or the theory of characteristic surfaces you mention as well, make apparent how the asked for reduction of the degrees of freedom of the Christoffel symbols happens?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a term in the source-free Maxwell equation. Since $F^{bc}$ is a second-rank tensor, you should get two $\Gamma$ terms. Have you tried writing down the general expression for $\nabla_a F^{bc}$, with all three indices distinct, and then contracting the indices $a,b$?

Comment: I agree, there are of course two connection terms for a rank two tensor. But one of these terms, the one 'missing' in my expression, is identically zero due in conjunction to the symmetry of the Christoffel symbols and the antisymmetry of the Faraday tensor. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think the logic here is backwards. "Photons following a null geodesic" is a [white lie for children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children). Indeed, strictly speaking, quantum particles don't have classical trajectories at all. The more adult version is that the wave fronts of electromagnetic waves with wavelengths much smaller than the curvature scales in the geometry will follow null geodesics, as a result of the [eikonal (or WKB) approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_approximation). Wald's book has a derivation of this.

Comment: In other words, there's certainly a way to go from Maxwell's equations to the equation for a null geodesic, but I don't think it's possible to go the other way. Indeed in the eikonal approximation, wavefronts in a massless scalar field will also obey the geodesic equation, so somehow you'd have to be able to reconstruct (at least) the the Klein-Gordon equation, if this derivation were possible at all. But I don't think it is, because you lose information when you apply the eikonal approximation.

Comment: The geodesic equations under this are not suitable for the propagation of light signals, because along the line of universe of propagation of a light ray the interval $ds=d\lambda=0$ and all the terms in the equation become infinite. if we replace $\frac{dx^{\rho}}{d\lambda }=k^{\rho}$ wave vector, the equation becomes : $\frac{dk^{\rho}}{d\lambda }+\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}k^{\mu}k^{\nu}=0$   with $k_{\rho}k^{\rho}=0$ (the square of the 4-vector is zero). Substituting into this expression $\frac{d\psi}{dx^{\rho} }=k^{\rho}$   ($\psi$ is the eikonal)...